# Asp.net mvc return to controller from jsonresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DelayReminder(string reminderId)
{
ReminderStatus rs = new ReminderStatus();


rs.BaseProps.RequesterUserInfo.UserID = SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser.UserID;


ReminderServiceHelper.InsertNewStatus(Convert.ToInt32(reminderId), rs);

return Json(apptype, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // Problem...
}
```

Instead of **return Json(apptype, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);** how can i write below ?

```
return RedirectToAction("GetLawDetail", "Law", new { _lawID = baseappid });
```

**If anybody wants to see Javascript:**

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Reminders/DelayReminder/',
                    data: {
                        'apptype': '@ViewData["apptype"]',
                        'baseappid': '@ViewData["baseappid"]',
                        'reminderId': $("#reminderId").val(),
                        'ddlDelayDuration': $("#ddlDelayDuration").val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {

                        if (result != null) {
                    }

                            ....
                            ..
```

How can i return to **Law controller to GetLawDetail actionresult inside of jsonresult** ?

Comment: Return url in json and redirect using js

Answer (score 0):

You can just return this action:

```
return GetLawDetail(baseappid)
```

You should also change the return type to Action result as pointed by @im1dermike.

Here's the complete code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DelayReminder(string reminderId)
{
ReminderStatus rs = new ReminderStatus();


rs.BaseProps.RequesterUserInfo.UserID = SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser.UserID;


ReminderServiceHelper.InsertNewStatus(Convert.ToInt32(reminderId), rs);

return GetLawDetail(apptype); // Problem...
}
```

**Although, it will return you the whole rendered page.**

Comment: He also has to change the return type to `ActionResult` I believe.

Comment: @soner what are you trying to accomplish in the first place? If GetLawDetail is in the same controller that this solution will work, otherwise it won't.

Comment: it is in another controller and also another actionresult

Comment: no another solution from anybody ? Sometimes i feel i am helpless because of Microsoft . I can not change any code in .net :)

Comment: I don't think there is any other solution to return another Action. Although you can create a controller with only one method (the one that's called from javascript) and inherit the controller that has GetLawDetail method so that you can call it as I've described in the answer

Comment: Return url in json and redirect using javascript

Comment: @soner if you want to redirect the user to that page, then you should go with Ehsan's option, just return the url that you need to redirect to, after that do `window.location.href = url'